# Determinant of A inverse

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse

If A is an invertible matrix of order 2 , then det (A inverse) is equal to

A) det (A)      B) 1 / (det A)       C) 1        D) 0

I tried approaching this question am not getting it
but
I KNOW ONE THING YES
(adj A) A = (det A)I
maybe it can help...

Comment: You need the formula for products of determinant

Comment: As an aside... a determinant of zero occurs if and only if that the matrix is not invertible... but $A$ being invertible clearly implies that $A^{-1}$ is invertible as well (*the inverse being $A$ again*) so you should have been able to rule the fourth option out immediately.  Another aside is that whatever identity you were to suppose should also work for $1\times 1$ matrices... who as you should know work exactly like ordinary real numbers.  You should know that for a real number $a$ you have $a^{-1} = \frac{1}{a}$...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\det XY = \det X \det Y$, and $\det I = 1$.

Comment: Understood it is option B. Thanks